# Angular post to ASP.NET Core 6 gets 400 while Postman works fine

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0, angular14

Originally I tried to send the argument as an object, but in ASP.NET Core 6, it is failing (400 error). From the many answers, I decided to stringify the object to a string and pass it like this:

```
var dtoAsJson: string = JSON.stringify(this.projectCreateInitDto);
this.http.post<ProjectDto>(baseUrl + 'Projects/CreateProject/', dtoAsJson).subscribe({
    next: (response: ProjectDto) => {
```

Stopping on the `http.post`, `dtoAsJson` was a text string of course.

The controller looks like this:

```
[Route("CreateProject")]
[HttpPost("{Jsondto}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ProjectAPIDto>> CreateProject(string Jsondto)
{
    ProjectAPICreateInitDto dto = Json.Decode<ProjectAPICreateInitDto>(Jsondto);
    Project project = _mapper.Map<Project>(dto);
}
```

I stop on the `Json.Decode` and `Jsondto` is null.

I've searched for solutions, but I'm stuck.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried a simpler example (same results).  This example only takes an ID parameter.  In addition I added headers - Content-type as application/json, accept as application/json.
The ID post looks like this:
this.http.post(baseUrl + 'Projects/DeleteProject', JSON.stringify(projectId), { 'headers': headers })
has non-zero value in Angular and null in the core6 controller.
??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending the `dtoAsJson`-object as the body of the POST request, but in the backend you are trying to receive it as a route parameter.

You could try the following:

```
[Route("CreateProject")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ProjectAPIDto>> CreateProject([FromBody] string Jsondto)
{
    ProjectAPICreateInitDto dto = Json.Decode<ProjectAPICreateInitDto>(Jsondto);
    Project project = _mapper.Map<Project>(dto);
}
```

**Hint how to further improve your code:**

I suppose your code will work without `JSON.stringify()`, if you use `[Route("CreateProject")]` and `[FromBody]` in the backend.

Comment: Thanks VERY much; I've been struggling with this all day.  I clearly don't understand the various ways to control this interface.  I will be studying and thanks to you, I now know what I'm looking for.  :-)